# The "borderwidth" change is not applied in "relief"

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

Python  Version : 3.8.0
Tkinter Version : 8.6.9

Even if I change the borderwidth, it is still very thin. What is the possible problem? Here is the code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

# Root
root = Tk()
root.title('Frame')
root.minsize(width = (int)(1920 / 5), height = (int)(1080 / 5))

# Frame
""" relief option
flat, solid, raised, sunken, groove, ridge
"""
frame_base = ttk.Frame(root, padding = 10)
frame_relief = ttk.Frame(
    frame_base, width = (int)(1920 / 5), height = (int)(1080 / 5),
    borderwidth = 10, relief = 'raised'
)

# Layout
frame_base.pack()
frame_relief.pack()

# Draw
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not all settings can be altered when using certain theme.  Try changing to other theme using `ttk.Style().theme_use()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all settings can be altered when using certain theme. Try changing to other theme using ttk.Style().theme_use(). – acw1668

I searched for using ttk.Style().theme_use() in the comments here and selected the theme, and the changes are now applied. Thank you very much for your help.